# how to preserve viewstate of radio button on postback

Tags: asp.net

i have a radio button linked with an image in my datalist where i have enabled paging,when i click radio button and do paging,the state of radio button is lost,how can i preserve the viewstate of this radio button.

Answer (score 0):

You'll probably need to post some code.  Is your RadioButton inside a DataList item template?  If so, when you do paging you are rebinding that control and everything inside it is recreated.

Comment: yea my radio button is inside datalist item template

Comment: In that case, you are losing the state because the pager rebinds the data.  You must save it in some intermediate way then, and restore the value during databinding.